# HTML rendered incorrectly in .NET

Tags: html, vb.net, xslt, line-breaks

I am trying to take the string "`<BR>`" in VB.NET and convert it to HTML through XSLT.  When the HTML comes out, though, it looks like this:

```
&lt;BR&gt;
```

I can only assume it goes ahead and tries to render it.  Is there any way I can convert those `&lt;/&gt;` back into the brackets so I get the line break I'm trying for?

Comment: A little code example would be helpful its difficult to see what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the XSLT has:

```
<xsl:output method="html"/>
```

---

edit: explanation from comments

By default XSLT outputs as XML(1) which means it will escape any significant characters. You can override this in specific instances with the attribute `disable-output-escaping="yes"` (intro [here](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N2215.html)) but much more powerful is to change the output to the explicit value of HTML which confides same benefit globally, as the following:

> - For script and style elements, replace any escaped characters (such
>     as & and >) with their actual values
>     (& and >, respectively).
> - For attributes, replace any occurrences of > with >.
> - Write empty elements such as `<br>`, `<img>`, and `<input>` without
>     closing tags or slashes.
> - Write attributes that convey information by their presence as
>     opposed to their value, such as
>     checked and selected, in minimized
>     form.

*from a solid IBM [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tiphtml.html) covering the subject, more recent coverage from stylusstudio [here](http://www.stylusstudio.com/w3c/xslt/N12184.htm)*

If HTML output is what you desire HTML output is what you should specify.

*(1) There is actually corner case where output defaults to HTML, but I don't think it's universal and it's kind of obtuse to depend on it.*

Comment: where in the xsl document does this line need to go?

Comment: joe: this should be your first tag within the <xsl:stylesheet>

Answer (score 0):

Try wraping it with `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;br&gt;</xsl:text>`

Comment: I've tried this, but it still converts it into HTML itself. (something to the effect of

 <xsl:text disable-...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about XSLT but..

One workaround might be using [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx) from System.Web namespace.

```
using System;
using System.Web;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&lt;br&gt;"));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Got it!  On top of the selected answer, I also did something similar to this on my string:

```
htmlString = htmlString.Replace("&lt;","<")
htmlString = htmlString.Replace("&gt;",">")
```

I think, though, that in the end, I may just end up using `<pre>` tags to preserve everything.

Answer (score -1):

The string "`<br>`" is already HTML so you can just `Response.Write("<br>")`.

But you meantion XSLT so I imagine there some transform going on.  In that case surely the transform should be inserting it at the correct place as a node.  A better question will likely get a better answer